# Website Alignment Width, Going Wrong

Tags: css, width, alignment, fluid

I've been working on pre-made web templates for almost a year now and I started off by making one of my own from scratch in PSD.
The Website can be located here:

**http://gamelabs.webege.com/**

My first time chopping a PSD to HTML/CSS as well. Nonetheless I got the thing to work on my laptop and I got it going until I viewed on multiple other browsers (Mac/iPad/Android) etc.
The whole thing got messed up and I have been searching for almost 3 days now still without a solution.
Have tried wrapping the website in margin: 0;, using other techniques like min/max-width, using positioning and still its aligned out, showing a bottom scroll on many browser screens but my own computer. Not going with overflow here because I can hide the scroll but the website is cut.
This is my first time going ahead with a website from scratch and I'm stuck at the ground level still.
I would also like to mention that I'm not planning to build a Responsive WD with grid.less or bootstrap, I just want the website to equally align on any browser window opened and be fluid in width.
**An excerpt from my choppy CSS is as:**

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#000;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
width: 100%;
        }

 #bottombar 
{ 
     left: 0px; 
     top: 750px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     z-index:1;
     background:url(images/foot.png) repeat-x;
} 

 #bottombarglow 
{ 
     left: 260px; 
     top: 733px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 800px;
     height: 51px;
     z-index:2;
     background:url(images/bottombarglow.png);
} 

 #topbar 
{ 
     left: 0px; 
     top: 0px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 100%;
     height: 82px;
     z-index:3;
     background:url(images/tb.png)repeat-x;
} 

 #blueline 
{ 
     left: 80px; 
     top: 648px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 1200px;
     height: 2px;
     z-index:4;
     background:url(images/blueline.png);
} 

 #bullets 
{ 
     left: 100px; 
     top: 660px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 860px;
     height: 87px;
     z-index:5;
     background:url(images/gallery_left.png);
}  

 #gallerybutton 
{ 
     left: 980px; 
     top: 670px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 257px;
     height: 67px;
     z-index:6;
     background:url(images/gallery.png);
} 

 #menu 
{ 
     left: 840px; 
     top: 14px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 450px;
     height: 54px;
     z-index:7;
     background:url(images/menu.png);
} 

 #footer 
{ 
     left: 156px; 
     top: 810px; 
     position: absolute;
     z-index:8;
     width: 400px;
     height: 98px;
     background:url(images/footer.png);
} 

 #logo 
{ 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 237px;
     height: 156px;
     z-index:9;
     background:url(images/logo.png);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- Title and CSS -->
<title>Game Art Labs | Play for Fun</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="icon" href="http://appbuzzsolutions.com/gal/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="logo"><a href="#" target="_self" class="logo"></a></div>
            <div id="topbar"></div>
            <div id="menu"></div>
            <div id="bullets"></div>
            <div id="gallerybutton"><a href="#" target="_self" class="gallery"></a></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="blueline"></div>
            <div id="bottombarglow"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
            <div id="bottombar"></div>
            <!-- BG SLIDER -->
<!-- set the active class on whichever image you want to show up as the default 
(otherwise this will be the last image) -->
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images/bg1.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1"/>
    <img src="images/bg2.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <img src="images/bg3.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <img src="images/bg4.png" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
    <img src="images/bg5.png" alt="Slideshow Image 5" />
    <img src="images/bg6.png" alt="Slideshow Image 6" class="active"  />
</div>
<!-- Java Starts -->

    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquerry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 4000 );
});

</script>
<!-- Java Ends -->
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is starting to eat my nerves a bit I would confess. The mistake here must be very basic but my knowledge is too. Hope someone can help me around with us. Will reply to any query.
Advance Thanks!
PS: I was inspired from Kabam.com while designing this.

Comment: Show your HTML. Also, how do you expect your site to be responsive when it's full of `absolute` positioning?

Comment: Hi feitla, sorry I never want it to be responsive, just fluid width!

Comment: Can you view HTML @ right click to view-source? From: http://gamelabs.webege.com/
It's too long to be posted here.

Comment: It is not for MY benefit, but for those ... who years down the road will come across this question with a similar problem but won't have any idea what the HTML was. It is for the value of the SO community. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I hate to say it and not to be a snob but a lot of your issues will be fixed with basic knowledge of web development (HTML, CSS). Your biggest issue you are facing right now is all that `absolute` positioning. Get rid of that. Your `#menu` DIV is taking up `1290px` so you're going to see a scrollbar on a lot of screens. You're `#topbar` should probably contain your `#menu`. Like this `<div id="topbar"><div id="menu"></div></div>` then the _CSS_ `#menu { float: right; width: 450px; height: 54px; background-image: url(images/menu.png);`. I realize your new to this, just keep truckin'.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to actually define the width of the **whole** webpage window, you need to do something like this:

```
body {
  width: 1600px;  //You can set it to any width
  padding: 0px;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Something simpler might be to add **px** after your measurements, otherwise, it won't know the unit of measurement, so it is void. Think of it like this. The world is about 250,000 long. Centimeters, or light years?

If your trying to change the **margin** of the page, you should do this:

```
body {
  width: 1000px;  //You can set it to any width
  margin: auto; //Auto will automatically center the whole page
  padding: 0px; //Don't forget px!
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Hello Time, just applied it and still the same results. Is there a good call on width you can make that should be relative on all browsers?

Comment: The issue is that whenever I use width: 100%; instead of PX, the page shows up fine. when using pixels instead, a thing or 2 gets aligned out.

Comment: Okay, well you could try to change__all__ of your measurements to percentages... Or you could try to manage to just use 100% for screen width.